# python eval(repr(file_handle)) fails with synax error

Tags: python, eval, filehandle, repr

I'm trying to pass a file handle through some hoops that lead to me wanting to pass the file handle as it's repr to pull it back into existence later on.  But, I've run into a problem.  The built-in repr for file handles is broken!

```
$ python3
Python 3.9.4 (default, Apr  6 2021, 00:00:00) 
[GCC 10.2.1 20201125 (Red Hat 10.2.1-9)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> f = open("x.out","a")
>>> f_copy = eval(repr(f))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
    <_io.TextIOWrapper name='x.out' mode='a' encoding='UTF-8'>
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

I can't find anything that would imply that I'd have to make my own custom subclass of io.TextIOWrapper or anything like that.  What am I missing?

Comment: That is not what `repr` does. It just produces a string with some object information according to its __repr__ method. You can't reproduce an object just based off a string.

Comment: If an object has a literal representation, `repr()` is supposed to return that. But not all objects have literals. It's conventional to use `<>` notation in these cases, and the error is expected.

Comment: Whatever you're trying to do with the file handle, this is not the way to do it. Do you know what you're trying to do?

Comment: @khelwood As a matter of fact, I *DO* know what I'm trying to do with it.  I'm trying to pass a file handle into a starmap_async function.  However, that chokes to death on the file handle, and doesn't even call the worker.  So, I was attempting to use an obvious pythonic method of eval(repr(x)).

Comment: I guess we have different understandings of what is obvious and pythonic.

Comment: If you are reading/writing multiple files, you could pass the filename instead of the handle and open each file inside of a worker.  If you are reading a single file, you could read the file contents once and capture that in a closure.  If you are writing to a single file, you will end up writing garbage to the file if you try to do it in parallel.  In all cases, `eval(repr(...))` seems like a hack.

Comment: you should send `filename` in `starmap` and function/process should open it. And if you have to write to file in many processes then you should rather send data to main process and only one process should write in file. When many process will try to write in one file then they may write data in wrong order or overwrite some parts.

Comment: 0x5453: It *is* a hack, because starmap chokes on the file object.  I'm not actually calling eval(repr()) like that.  I'm passing the repr as a parameter into the worker, and calling eval on it.  

furas: I'm trying to avoid the overhead of opening the file so many times.  (Really, it's not that many, but I'm trying to reduce the overhead as much as possible.)

Comment: I think I have found a workable solution.  Instead of passing the File object (which doesn't work), or the repr (which also doesn't work, but probably should...), I am passing the file descriptor along, and then using write() instead of print().